# Android : How to make TextView with compound bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, textview

i want to create a TextView with compound Bitmap, i know android support creating TextView with compound drawables but i want to compound Bitmap as i downloaded images online

note : i don't want to make LinearLayout holds imageview and textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in XML code. This adds a `Drawable` at the top. You can change it to left, right or bottom:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/yourdrawable"
/>
```

**Edit**

Sorry, totally misread your question. You can do this in code by creating a BitmapDrawable and then using that as a compound Drawable. More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html